# "To be good" or "being good" as subject

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

I was doing an exercise where I had to cross out the incorrect forms:

> **Being / To be / Be** good is easy; what is difficult is **being / to be / be** just.
>   (Victor Hugo)

In both cases I chose **To be**, which turned out to be wrong.

But later I [discovered this](http://www.sparknotes.com/lit/doriangray/quotes/) quote by Oscar Wilde

> **To be good** is **to be** in harmony with one’s self

So, my question is, apart from the fact that it was a quotation, is it correct to say *To be good is easy; what is difficult is to be just.*?

Answer (score 1):

For this native speaker, for your sentence

> **Being** good is easy, what is difficult is **being** just.

a better cadence might be

> **To be** good is easy, **to be** just is difficult,

with equivalent meaning and sounds more formal than

> **Being** good is easy, **being** just is difficult.

Also keep in mind *Victor Hugo* was French, and *Wilde* was a Irish, a native English speaker.